# How to change page numbers within a LaTeX document?

Tags: page-breaking, page-numbering

I am preparing a teaching portfolio with some attachments. I want to have Arabic page numbers for chapter/section pages I write, and Roman page numbers for attachments in between.

For example, if I have section pages starting from 1 up to 4, and then two attachments numbered i, ii, next restarting section pages 5-8, and finally, other attachments numbered iii-v.

I used `\pagebreak` command but I was unable to have a continuing numbering style. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome here!

You can define two commands, say `\switchtoroman` and `\switchtoarabic` with associated counters, like so:---

```
\newcounter{lastromanpage}
\setcounter{lastromanpage}{1}
\newcounter{lastarabicpage}
\setcounter{lastarabicpage}{1}
\newcommand\switchtoroman{
  \setcounter{lastarabicpage}{\value{page}}
  \clearpage
  \ifnum\value{lastromanpage}=1\else
  \stepcounter{lastromanpage}\fi
  \setcounter{page}{\value{lastromanpage}}
  \renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
}
\newcommand\switchtoarabic{
  \setcounter{lastromanpage}{\value{page}}
  \clearpage
  \ifnum\value{lastarabicpage}=1\else
  \stepcounter{lastarabicpage}\fi
  \setcounter{page}{\value{lastarabicpage}}
  \renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}
}
```

Then either command should clear the current page and start the new page with the appropriate counter.  Although this may need to be tested, it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.